# Creating a UIView Renderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I am having issues creating an Renderer in Xamarin.

I am trying to display another view inside the Renderer, but it just won't work. How should I set this up? I am confuse as to how I should go about setting this type of renderer. is `protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<PdfView> e)` even necessary?

I have a page class like this:

```
public class PdfView : ContentView
    {

    }

    public class PdfPage : ContentPage
    {
        public PdfPage (ProjectViewModel _viewModel)
        {

            this.Content = new PdfView ();
        }
    }
```

Renderer:

```
[assembly:ExportRenderer(typeof(PdfView), typeof(PdfViewRenderer))]
namespace iOS
{
    public class PdfViewRenderer : ViewRenderer<PdfView, UIScrollView >
    {

        protected override void OnElementChanged (ElementChangedEventArgs<PdfView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (e.OldElement != null)
            {
                return;
            }

            Add (new UIView (){ BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray});

        }


    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling

```
Add (new UIView (){ BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray});
```

Try instead calling SetNativeControl

```
SetNativeControl(new UIView (){ BackgroundColor = UIColor.Gray});
```

That should bind the native iOS control you just created to your custom xamarin.forms view.

Comment: Awesome, You made my Monday morning worth waking up to.